# Drawer can be seen when swiping back

Tags: react-native, native-base, react-native-router-flux

I'm developing mobile application with the below technologies.
- react-native
- native-base (Especially, `Drawer` component)
- react-native-router-flux
And I have a problem with mine.

My application has Drawer on the left side, and it can be shown from the left side on the screen when clicking the icon on the header.
However, when swiping back, the Drawer component can be seen but not as Drawer, it is like a screen that attaches on the left side.

This link is the GIF animation that reproduces my problem.
https://gyazo.com/a9109844199bae04f898431edbeaddbc

These are my code.

- DrawerComponent

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Drawer, Hdeader, Left, Icon } from 'native-base';
import SidebarContainer from '../component/SidebarConmponent';

:
export default class DrawerComponent extends Component {

:
render() {
    return (
      <Drawer
        ref={(ref) => { this.drawer = ref; }}
        content={<SidebarComponent navigator={this._navigator} userId={this.props.userId} firebase={this.props.firebase}/>}
        openDrawerOffset={0.4}
        tapToClose={true}
        onClose={() => this.closeDrawer}
        onOpen={() => this.openDrawer}
        styles={{ height: 100 }}
        side={'left'}
        type={'overlay'}
      >
<Header style={{ backgroundColor: 'transparent' }}>
            <Left style={{ flexDirection: 'row'}}>
              <Icon onPress={this.openDrawer.bind(this)} type='MaterialIcons' name='menu' style={{ color: 'white', justifyContent: 'center' }} />
            </Left>
{this.props.children}
</Drawer>
:
```

- SiderbarComponent

```
:
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container, Content, Header, Left, Icon, List, ListItem } from 'native-base';

export default class SidebarContainer extends Component {
:
  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
          <View style={{ height: height }}>
            <Content>
              <List>
                <ListItem button>
                  <Icon type='Ionicons' name='md-home' />
                  <Text style={{ paddingLeft: 10 }}Home</Text>
                </ListItem>
              </List>
            </Content>
          </View>
        </Container>
    )
  }
}
```

- HomeComponent

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';
import DrawerComponent from '../component/DrawerComponent';

export default class HomeComponent extends Component {
  render(
    return (
      <DrawerComponent>
        <Text>Home</Text>
      </DrawerComponent>
    )
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Home component extends from wrong.need to extends from Component import 
try this like this

```
import React from 'react'
import { Text } from 'react-native';

import DrawerComponent from '../component/DrawerComponent';

export default class Home extends React.Component  {
 render(){
  return (
   <DrawerComponent>
     <Text>Home</Text>
   </DrawerComponent>
        )
     }
 }
```

Comment: I'm sorry, that was my mistake. Home Component extends Component provided react module correctly.

Comment: did you try changing extends from Components?

Comment: What I meant to say is I made a mistake when I copy and paste my code into this post. So in my actual HomeComponent, it extends Component provided react module. I have already modified this post.